# What is the command to load a Soft Input Panel DLL in Windows Mobile 6.5?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll, windows-mobile, soft-input-panel

I'm trying to test and later build some existing, very old code for a custom soft input panel DLL on Windows Mobile 6.5.

When I compile the code to test in Visual Studio 2008 -- the last version which supports the old eVC project file -- I get a message indicating that only a DLL has been produced and as a result it cannot be executed directly. However, the IDE advises me that I can specify a command to load the DLL. What command should I be using to load a soft input panel DLL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input panel's in Windows CE aren't loaded by any specific program, they're loaded by the OS itself (likely by GWES, but you'd have to walk the CE sources to verify that if you really, really want to know).  The net result of that is that you can't set any "command line" in the debugger to get it to load your SIP.  The downside is that you can't get use the debugger (you could use the Platform Builder debugger if it was generic Windows CE and you had a BSP).

To "register" your InputPanel, you simply need to create the approprate registry entries ([documented in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa452746.aspx))

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\CLSID\{your object CLSID}
    InprocServer32=reg_sz:"\\Windows\\mysiplib.dll"
    IsSIPInputMethod=reg_sz:"1" ;note this is a string, not a dword
    DefaultIcon=regsz:"\\Windows\\mysiplib.dll,0"
```

To get it to "appear", you probably have to go into the Control Panel, under Setings->Personal->Input.

Once loaded, you can't unload the SIP without removing the registry entries and then a soft reset.

Comment: ctacke, I followed your suggestion above on CE7, but when I select my customized SIP keyboard in the Control Panel->Input Panel, it does not save my selection because when I go back to check by opening Control Panel->Input Panel again it uses the default keyboard.  Does that mean my customized SIP dll does not work? thanks

Comment: Sounds like your SIP is not loading.  Maybe it has an error and is failing?

Comment: thank you for responding.  So I have the SIP project that has been working for Windows Mobile and CE6, and now I'm just porting it to CE7 without changing any code except adding new project configuration to compile for CE7 and I can build it successfully with VS2008.  How can I check if the dll cannot load or it has error because I don't receive any feedback from Control Panel->Input Panel.

Comment: Strange.  If it worked under CE 6, I would expect it to still work.  I'd be inclined to look in the WEC 7 source for it's SIP and see if maybe the registry key that it's looking at changed or anything along those lines.  I'd also try the CE 6.0 binary directly under WEC 7

Comment: That is what I am afraid of that they change the registration location, but I haven't found any documentation on Windows Embedded 7 that explains about CE7 SIP.

Comment: I think I need to add one new registry for it to work and it's in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SIP\Installed"{my object ID}"